# hashCode implementation for "equals any of some fields are equal"

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I want objects of a particular class to be equal if *one* of their fields are equal. How can I write a consistent hashCode method for such a class?

(Disclaimer because I know this is not best practice: The class is a wrapper for another class and should be used for keys in Maps. It is intended that two different of these objects with one equal field would result in the same Map entry. Actually each of the fields would identify the underlying object on their own but I do not always have the same identifying field for two objects available. I cannot control and therefore change this "ambiguous" identification mechanism. Alternative solutions to tackle this are also welcome.)

Are there strategies for implementing hashCode() accordingly? I only know of implementations involving conjunctions (as with &&) in equals. How to make sure that hashCode() is the same if either of the fields is equal?

Here is the simplified equals method for which I would like to write a consistent hashCode() implementation:

```
public boolean equals(C other)
{
    return (field1 != null && field1.equals(other.field1))
            || (field2 != null && field2.equals(other.field2))
            || (field3 != null && field3.equals(other.field3));
}
```

EDIT: as per the input data, no cases like (1, 2, 3) equals (1, 6, 7) can occur. The objects are only produced such that some of the fields can be null, but not contradicting as in the example. Simply put in practise the only combinations equal to (1, 2, 3) should be (1, 2, 3), (1, null, null), (null, 2, null), (1, 2, null) and so forth. I acknowledge that this approach is not particularly robust.

Comment: so use that field only in your hashcode implementation.

Comment: That equality relation is not transitive.  You're going to break the contract anyway.

Comment: there are multiple fields and if any of them are (pairwise) equal for two instances, these two instances are considered "equal"

Comment: there are several ways to do that but you should take a look on the contract to override equals() and hashCode() method implementation.

Comment: The problem with this is that (1, 2, 3, 4) and (3, 4, 5, 6) compare equal as do (3, 4, 5, 6) and (5, 6, 7, 8) but (1, 2, 3, 4) and (5, 6, 7, 8) do not compare equal.

Comment: what I did not mention above is that the case a.field1.equals(b.field1) && !a.field2.equals(b.field2) (or similar combinations) cannot happen (as per the processed input data), would excluding this not make equal transitive again? -- I know this is kind of hacky but so far I have not found a cleaner solution

Comment: Why do you need this weird `equals` method at all?  Can't you define a function object that implements this logic and only use it explicitly in isolated places where you actually need it.  It will make your code a lot cleaner and avoid many confusing bugs in the future.

Comment: @5gon12eder this is what I wanted to do in the first place but I would like to use this with HashMap and I cannot provide a custom equals-Implementation. Since the type has no useful ordering I tried to avoid TreeSet with a custom Comparator

Answer (score 2):

You can't use any fields to implement the `hashCode` because the field aren't equals all the time.

Your `hashCode` method needs to return the same value for equals objects all the time. As only one field needs to be equal in your `equals` method, and it isn't always the same, your only option is to return a constant in your `hashCode` method.

The implementation is inefficient but it is valid and consistent with equals.

The implementation could be:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP is probably asking if "Only one field" can be used to implement equals() and hashCode().

Comment: @ha9u63ar - In that case, the answer is *no*. Equals() can return true on field3 but hasCode() might be generated based on field1.

Comment: @ha9u63ar Thanks, I misunderstood the question, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` using just one field of your object class. Everyone will probably advise you against it. The general practice is to ensure that you compare all the fields and ensure that they are all equal in order to call `.equals()`. `hashCode()` uses `.equals()` in order to hash those objects. However, if you can control what you are doing, you can simply use the `hashCode()` of a particular field of your object and override .equals() and `.hashCode()` based on that (but again, not advisable).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only solution is this

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually, there are 2^32 more solutions I can think of…  The (2^32 + 1)st solution is throwing an exception.

Comment: @Prashant - This is the *correct* solution. The `equality` contract itself is flawed, don't expect` hashCode()` without flaws.

Comment: indeed this would work but it also degenerates HashMaps and thus degrades performance, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you implement `equals` as not being an equivalence relation, the Java collections framework bails out anyway.

Comment: @TheLostMind that i got  :D

Comment: @JayK - There is a supplemented `hash()` method in HashMap for poor hashCodes :P

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `equals()` in the question

```
  public boolean equals(C other) {
    //TODO: you have to check if other != null...

    return (field1 != null && field1.equals(other.field1)) ||
           (field2 != null && field2.equals(other.field2)) ||
           (field3 != null && field3.equals(other.field3));
  }
```

is ***incorrect one***. When implementing equals we have to ensure that

```
  a.equals(a)
  if a.equals(b) then b.equals(a)
  if a.equals(b) and b.equals(c) then a.equals(c)
```

**Counter example** for the 1st rule is the instance where *all fields 
of comparison* (`field1, field2, field3`) are `null`:

```
  MyObject a = new MyObject();
  a.setField1(null);
  a.setField2(null);
  a.setField3(null);

  a.equals(a); // <- return false
```

***Counter example*** for the 3d rule:

```
  MyObject a = new MyObject();
  a.setField1("1"); // field2 and field3 == null 

  MyObject b = new MyObject();
  b.setField1("1"); // field3 == null 
  b.setField2("2"); 

  MyObject c = new MyObject();
  c.setField2("2");  // field1 and field3 == null

  a.equals(b); // true (by field1)
  b.equals(c); // true (by field2)
  a.equals(c); // false!
```

And that's why there's *no solution* for `hashCode()`...

Comment: you are correct, but this case cannot happen in practice because of how the objects would be created from the input data (unfortunately I am not allowed to elaborate on the use case, I might try to clarify the question later but it seems I should rather look for a better approach altogether)

Comment: @JayK: your implementation also violates 3d rule (see my edit)

Comment: You are right, I have not considered that case yet. If I should come back to this approach, I will have to evaluate how that relates to the actual input and surrounding algorithms and think of an appropriate "fix" if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the point that as you say it is not a good practice, I think one way you can achieve this is maintanting a reference to the other object in each of the objects and computing hashCode based on the equality of the fields:

```
public class Test {
    private String field1;
    private Integer field2;

    private Test other;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public int getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(int field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public Test getOther() {
        return other;
    }

    public void setOther(Test other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (other == null) {
            return super.hashCode();
        }

        int hashCode = 1;
        if (field1 != null && field1.equals(other.field1)) {
            hashCode = 31 * hashCode + (field1 == null ? 0 : field1.hashCode());
        }
        if (field2 != null && field2.equals(other.field2)) {
            hashCode = 31 * hashCode + field2.hashCode();
        }
        if (hashCode == 1) {
            hashCode = super.hashCode();
        }
        return hashCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Test other) {
        return (field1 != null && field1.equals(other.field1))
                || (field2 != null && field2.equals(other.field2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.setField1("a");
        t1.setField2(1);

        Test t2 = new Test();
        t2.setField1("a");
        t2.setField2(1);

        t1.setOther(t2);
        t2.setOther(t1);

        System.out.println("Equals: " + t1.equals(t2));
        System.out.println("Hash 1: " + t1.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Hash 2: " + t2.hashCode());

        t2.setField2(2);
        System.out.println("Equals: " + t1.equals(t2));
        System.out.println("Hash 1: " + t1.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Hash 2: " + t2.hashCode());

        t2.setField1("b");
        System.out.println("Equals: " + t1.equals(t2));
        System.out.println("Hash 1: " + t1.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Hash 2: " + t2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Alternative solutions to tackle this are also welcome.

I would never mess with equals() & hashCode(). Simply implement them correctly for the objects. Write a custom comparator meeting your needs and use a collection that supports a custom comparator (e.g. [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) or [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-)) to perform your lookup.

**Sample comparator:**

```
public class SingleFieldMatchComparator implements Comparator<Key> {

  public int compare(Key key1, Key key2) {
    if (key1 == null) {
      if (key2 == null) {
        return 0;
      }
      else {
        return 1;
      }
    } else if (key2 == null) {
      return -1;
    }

    int result = ObjectUtils.compare(key1.getField1(), key2.getField1());
    if (result == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    result = ObjectUtils.compare(key1.getField2(), key2.getField2());
    if (result == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    return ObjectUtils.compare(key1.getField3(), key2.getField3());
  }

}
```

Note: above uses [ObjectUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) to reduce the code a bit. Can be replaced with a private method if the dependency isn't worth it.

**Sample program:**

```
Map<Key,Key> myMap = new TreeMap<Key,Key>(new SingleFieldMatchComparator());
Key key = new Key(1, 2, 3);
myMap.put(key, key);
key = new Key(3, 1, 2);
myMap.put(key, key);

System.out.println(myMap.get(new Key(null, null, null)));
System.out.println(myMap.get(new Key(1, null, null)));
System.out.println(myMap.get(new Key(null, 2, null)));
System.out.println(myMap.get(new Key(null, null, 2)));
System.out.println(myMap.get(new Key(2, null, null)));
```

**Output:**

```
null
1,2,3
1,2,3
3,1,2
null
```